# Script acting strange in bash_profile (but just under X)

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile

I have made a simple .sh script which checks every minute whether a particular file is empty or not, and if it is not empty, makes a led on my laptop blink at 0.5Hz.
I call this script from my `.bash_profile`.

Whenever I am in TTY, the thing works flawlessly (to say: when the file is not empty the led on my lappy blinks at that precise frequency).

But when I run X (I use Xmonad/urxvt, invoked via `startx` if that could help) something strange happens. The frequency of the blink is erratic, it slows down (a bit) the machine and when I call `top` I see various sudo processes (the one I call to turn the led on or off).

It is the same behavior as if I called the script three or four times.

I don't know how to diagnose the problem. The manual says `.bash_profile` gets read once (at login time). Can you help me out?

```
# blink mail led

blinkTime="0.2"
checkTime="60"


while true; do
  hasIt=$(cat ~/someFolder/hazText.txt) # 1: has text

  if [ $hasIt -eq "1" ]
  then
    echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness > /dev/null
    sleep $blinkTime
    echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness > /dev/null
    sleep $blinkTime
  else
    sleep $checkTime
  fi

done
```

Comment: Can you share the script? I guess you have some kind of sleep logic in there to slow down the looping of the script. Bear in mind that `PATH` variables may not be available if you run scripts this way. So if you are calling `sleep` for example you actually have to use the absolute path (can be determined via `which sleep`) otherwise your system won't be able to execute it.

Comment: Also, some distributions cause `.bashrc` to source `.bash_profile` that could explain why the script is called many times.

Comment: yes I can http://paste.debian.net/9196/ (also, I run Debian stable)

Comment: Don't know why your script gets called multiple times but you can fix that by using a lockfile. This [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1715151/17413) shows you one way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand your *echo* lines. Doesn't  `sudo echo "1" | /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness > /dev/null` work?

Comment: @Nifle no, that uses a pipe to pass a string through a _file_, he uses `tee` to actually write to the file.

Comment: _Is_ your script running multiple times? Check with `ps aux | grep SCRIPTNAME`

Comment: echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness > /dev/null
Why not:
sudo echo "0" > /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness
?
Add script execution to /etc/rc.local and remove from .bash* to avoid duplicates, or use lock file.

Comment: @september: `| sudo tee` is needed because a normal redirect would be done (or rather, would fail) in the calling shell, before `sudo` even launches. See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)

Comment: @Gordon, @september: Although `sudo sh –c "echo '0' > /sys/class/leds/led:alarm/brightness"` would probably work.  But using `tee` is a clever trick.

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` is executed when Bash starts as a login shell, not "at login time" as you wrote. This means that every time Bash starts either with `"--login"` option or as `"-bash"`, it will read and execute `.bash_profile`. Most likely starting your X session implicitly starts several Bash instances (since it's a default shell on Linux). Some of these instances probably happen to be login shells, your script gets called severals times, which makes your LED go into disco mode.

The solution to your problem would be to move the script out of the `.bash_profile`, and either create a `cron` job for it, or rewrite it using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-info).